# Wordpress PHP create or add to query string

Tags: php, wordpress, get, uri

I'm working on a WordPress plugin, I have a short code that gets a variable form the query string in the url to move forward of backwards a year.

What I was thinking of doing was to get the uri without the query string then getting the query variable adding or subtracting one then appending the query on the the uri and printing it as a link.

It's since occurred to me that if the user is using the queries in there WordPress permalink this would remove the query for the page id.

So I need some help working out how to generate the link by either creating a query or adding to the current query if there is one. e.g.

```
    http://example.com/wordpress/page/?vyear=2014
    http://example.com/wordpress/?page_id=26&vyear=2014
```

I'm also not sure how to update the query variable if there are other variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I cant seems to find any way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Wordpress, you can use [add_query_arg](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg):

From the docs:

```
<?php
// Parameters as separate arguments
add_query_arg( $param1, $param2, $old_query_or_uri );

// Parameters as array of key => value pairs
add_query_arg( array('key1' => 'value1', ...), $old_query_or_uri );
?>
```

You can pass in a parameter and a value (or an associative array), along with the the existing URL, and it will generate a properly formatted URL for you. There also the companion [remove_query_arg](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_query_arg)

Comment: You're welcome. I would recommend checking out the WordPress documentation - there's a lot of functionality built-in, and compared with most of the software I use, it's very well documented.